# Playback of Facebook live video doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: facebook, mobile, browser, live-streaming

I'm using the video embed feature (via iframe or JavaScript) to embed a Facebook live video on a website. This works fine on desktop, but the video won't play on mobile devices (iOS & Android). It shows the image but asks the user to play the video in the Facebook app. Is there an option to directly play it in the browser?

This is the embed code:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your embedded video player code -->
<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/[PAGE-ID]/videos/[VIDEO-ID]/" data-width="500" data-show-text="false"></div>
```